# Wordpress PHP Include inserting extra spaces

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a HTML page that is dynamically regenerated every hour into my wordpress site, so I can not just insert the raw HTML code.

My issue is when I use

```
<?php
include 'http://localhost:99/document.html';
?>
```

It is literally printing each HTML character one by one. [image: Image here]

In the view source it displays each character but with a space in between
[image]

I have tried include, readfile, and file_get_contents, and all three yield the same results. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is your web server's encoding? If not configured correctly, it can cause problems like this.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE My encoding is set to utf-8 in IIS and I have looked at the HTTP Headers and it also indicates utf-8. Should it be set to something else?

Comment: can you share the html that is generated? how is that file being generated?

Comment: Just to be clear, visiting `http://localhost:99/document.html` _directly_ in your browser does not show the same problem? (And if if doesn't - that document _does_ get interpreted as UTF-8, and not something else?)

Comment: localhost is just your machine, so it's not available world wide. You need to paste the content somewhere else so that we can dig into it